# How to fix this "Unable to publish push notification; err = Published push notification to not push-enabled channel" with ably

Tags: flutter, websocket, flutter-notification, ably-realtime

I'm trying to use push notifications with ably in a flutter app but I'm getting this error please help me solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must enable [channel rule](https://ably.com/docs/general/channel-rules-namespaces) on Ably Console to enable push notifications for a channel.

To do this

- [Login](https://ably.com/login) to Ably console.
- Click on the application you want the channel rule for.
- Click on Settings
- Click on 'Add new rule' button next to 'Channel rules' section
- Enter channel or namespace id
- Tick 'Push notifications enabled'
- Click on 'Create channel rule' and you should be good to go

I hope that helps!